# What is D's version of C++'s system function?

Tags: d

How do I execute a command in the system shell in D (preferably Tango)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[tango.stdc.stdlib](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/docs/stable/tango.stdc.stdlib.html) should, as [tango's docs](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/wiki/ChapterC) say,

> provide[s] an essentially complete
>   interface to the standard C library
>   (according to ISO/IEC 9899:1999)

(`stdlib.h` is where C defines `system`).

Answer (score 16):

Phobos provides std.process ([D1.x](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/phobos/std_process.html)) ([D2.x](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_process.html)). Then you would just use the system() call. The exec commands are also available here.